# How to create overloading + on the other side

Tags: c++, oop, templates, operator-overloading

I have matrix class and overloaded operator + working with other matrices and scalars. When I try to use it like mat2=mat+3; that works ok but if i change scalar and matrix mat2=3+mat; it says "Invalid operands to binary expression('int' and Matrix<3, 4>')" (3,4 is rows and columns in this matrix).
How I understand I haven't overloaded + for this cases but I don't find how to overload it

```
Matrix operator+(const T &a) {
    Matrix<row, col, T> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
            result.elements[i][j] = elements[i][j] + a;
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Overload the operator `+` to take an `int` as its lvalue.

Comment: but if I overloaded this with T why it doesnt work with any types?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11681308/179910 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/20213363/179910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion: define `operator+=()` as member function of the class but define `operator+()` as a couple of external functions (`friend` to the class, if necessary). Maybe define the `operator+()` functions using the `operator+=()` method to avoid code duplication.

Something as (caution: code not tested and supposing `Matrix` has a copy constructor)

```
// method of the Matrix class
Matrix operator+= (T const & a)
 {
   for ( auto i = 0 ; i < row ; ++i )
      for ( auto j = 0 ; j < col ; ++j ) 
          elements[i][j] += a;

    return *this;
 }

// ordinary (external to the Matrix class) function
template <int row, int col, typename T>
Matrix<row, col, T> operator+ (Matrix<row, col, T> m, T const & a)
 { return m += a; }

// ordinary (external to the Matrix class) function
template <int row, int col, typename T>
Matrix<row, col, T> operator+ (T const & a, Matrix<row, col, T> m)
 { return m += a; }
```

Observe that both `operator+()` receive the `Matrix` value by copy.

Answer (score 2):

That function is probably in your class. But how can you add an overload to `int`? Does `int` even *have* a class? Is it time to scream and panic?

Take a deep breath and look at the [difference between global operator and member operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1145022/2602718) overloads. You can actually overload for `int` in the global scope, which will probably look like:

```
template <typename T>
Matrix<T> operator+(const T &a, Matrix<T> &m) { return m + a; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use

```
mat2=3+mat;
```

You have to overload the operator as a non-member function. Fortunately, its implementation is very simple.

```
template <typename T>
Matrix<T> operator+(const T &a, Matrix<T> const& mat) {
    return (mat + a);
}
```

Ideally, you should overload both versions as non-member functions.

```
template <typename T>
Matrix<T> operator+(Matrix<T> const& mat, const T &a ) {
   ...
}
```